# Proof Explaination: Show the set of measurable sets is closed under finite union

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure, proof-explanation

I have a proof of the above claim but I think there are some mistakes, I have highlighted them I hope someone could help figure out exactly what is wrong.

> Given $\omega$ an outer measure on set $M$
>
> Given  $\Sigma = \{E \subseteq M | \forall X \subseteq M,
>  \omega(X)=\omega(X \cap E)+ \omega(X \cap E^c)\}$ which is the set of
>   all measurable sets on $M$

**Problem Statement**: **$A, B \in \Sigma$, then show $A \cup B \in \Sigma$**

**Proof**:
Since $A \in \Sigma$, therefore $\forall X \in M, \omega(X)=\omega(X \cap A)+ \omega(X \cap A^c)$

We can also write $\omega(X \cap A^c) =  \omega((X \cap A^c) \cap B) + \omega((X \cap A^c) \cap B^c)$, for $B \in \Sigma$

Therefore, $\omega(X)=\omega(X \cap A)+ \omega(X \cap A^c) = \omega(X \cap A) + \omega((X \cap A^c) \cap B) + \omega((X \cap A^c) \cap B^c) = \omega(X \cap A) + \omega((X \cap A^c) \cap B) + \omega(X \cap (A \cup B)^c)$

(So if $\omega(X \cap (A \cup B)) = \omega(X \cap A) + \omega((X \cap A^c) \cap B)$ then we are done.)

Note that $A \cap B \subset M$, then we can write $\omega(X \cap (A \cup B)) = \omega(X \cap (A \cup B) \cap A) + \omega(X \cap (A \cup B) \cap A^c)$

Then it is true that  $\omega(X \cap (A \cup B) \cap A) = \omega(X \cap A)$ and $\omega(X \cap (A \cup B) \cap A^c) = \omega(X \cap (A \cap A^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)) = \omega(X \cap \varnothing \cup (B \cap A^c)) =  \omega(X \cap B \cap A^c)$

Thus $\omega(X \cap (A \cup B)) = \omega(X \cap A) +  \omega(X \cap B \cap A^c)$.

**Then $\omega(X) = \omega(X \cap (A \cup B)) + \omega(X \cap (A \cup B)^c)$
So this proves that $\Sigma$ is closed under finite union.**

---

> Questions:
>
> 1. How do you justify:  $\omega(X)=\omega(X \cap A)+ \omega(X \cap A^c) = \omega(X \cap A) + \omega((X \cap A^c) \cap B) + \omega((X \cap
>     A^c) \cap B^c) = \omega(X \cap A) + \omega((X \cap A^c) \cap B) +
>     \omega(X \cap (A \cup B)^c)$ 
>      Specifically: How do you show that $\omega((X \cap A^c)
>     \cap B^c) = \omega(X \cap (A \cup B)^c)$?
> 2. How do you justify the statement after "Then it is true that"  $\omega(X \cap (A \cup B) \cap A) = \omega(X \cap A)$ ? What
>      simplification was done to make the LHS equal to the RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your questions rely on facts about sets, not outer measure:

First, $\omega((X\cap A^c) \cap B^c) = \omega(X \cap (A \cup B)^c)$ because
$$
(X \cap A^c) \cap B^c
= X \cap (A^c \cap B^c)
= X \cap (A \cup B)^c,
$$
where we used the associativity of intersections and De Morgan's Law.

Second, $\omega(X \cap (A \cup B) \cap A) = \omega(X \cap A)$ because
$$
X \cap (A \cup B) \cap A
= X \cap A.
$$
This is because $A \subseteq A \cup B$, so $(A \cup B) \cap A = A$.

Comment: Wait wait I think I might be going crazy. So we don't use distribution for: $(X \cap A^c) \cap B^c = (X \cap B^c) \cap (A^c \cap B^c)$? Because the difficulty was that I had no idea what  $X \cap B^c$ is.

Comment: @Lookbehindyou you *could* write it that way since it's true. But here specifically, you can use the fact that $(X \cap A^c) \cap B^c = A \cap (A \cup B)^c$ since it helps you in the proof.

Comment: Then $X \cap B^c = X$? I had trouble digesting this part, how do we justify this?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou, No, $X \cap B^c \neq X$ unless $X \subseteq B^c$. Since $B^c \subseteq X$, $X \cap B^c = B^c$. Were you able to follow my associativity and De Morgan's Law argument?

Comment: Yes, but you said the distribution also works so $(X \cap A^c) \cap B^c = (X \cap B^c) \cap (A^c \cap B^c)$ so in order to have $X \cap (A \cup B)^c$, we must have $X \cap B^c = X$ shouldn't we?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou No, not necessarily. Just because $(X \cap B^c) \cap (A^c \cap B^c) = X \cap (A^c \cap B^c)$, it is not necessarily true that $X \cap B^c = X$. In general, if $X \cap Y = Z \cap Y$, then it doesn't necessarily follow that $X = Z$.